# Xamarin.Forms remove item from ListView and add it to another

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have 2 list views like so:

```
<ListView x:Name="Qualifications" ItemSelected="Qualifications_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding text}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ListView x:Name="QualificationsSelected" ItemSelected="QualificationsSelected_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding text}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And here are my ItemSelected methods:

```
void Qualifications_ItemSelected(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = sender as ListView;

            var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem;
        }

        void QualificationsSelected_ItemSelected(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = sender as ListView;

            var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem;
        }
```

My question is, how do I remove the selected from one list to another?

I have tried the following:

```
void Specialities_ItemSelected(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = sender as ListView;

            var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem as SpecialitiesClass;

            specialities.Remove(selectedItem);

            Specialities.ItemsSource = specialities;


        }
```

But it did not work, it did not remove it from the ListView.

Thanks,

Comment: you remove it from the first list's ItemsSource and add it to the second's

Comment: @Jason I have updated my question with what I tried and it did not work :(

Comment: that should work, although it's not the most efficient approach.  Did you verify that the item is actually removed from `specialities` after calling `Remove()`?  And your original post was about `Qualifications` now you are using `Specialities`, are you sure you're looking at the correct code?

Comment: I am doing it for both....let me check if its actually getting removed

Comment: It is getting removed from the list.

Comment: you can try using an ObservableCollection as the ItemsSource, or sometimes setting the ItemsSource to null before reassigning it can help

Comment: How do I convert the list to ObservableCollection

Comment: use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`

Comment: Trying that now.

Comment: Yup that worked. Thanks for your help....again